# Use of recentdocs registry key

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I am trying to find out the use of the RecentDocs registry key. From my knowledge, I have read that it is used to populate the recent files in the start menu. I tried modifying the values of the key trying to locate this place at the start menu but I am unable to do so. Can somebody show me where specifically in the start menu or what feature is this key responsible for.

Comment: Hint; look for `MRU` (Most Recently Used).

Answer (score 0):

The RecentDocs Key is extremely complicated to use and there is no
documentation of its structure. Frankly, I wouldn't try to modify it manually.

To be convinced, see the article
[Updates to the RecentDocs Key in Windows 10](https://forensic4cast.com/2019/03/the-recentdocs-key-in-windows-10/),
where you will learn about duplicate entries and sub-keys and
binary structures.

If you only wish to dump the contents, you could use the NirSoft utility
[RecentFilesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/recent_files_view.html).

If you wish to understand the binary structure of an entry, you could
examine the source-code of the
[RegRipper project](https://github.com/keydet89/RegRipper3.0)
and especially its `recentdocs_tln.pl` plugin that dumps these items.

This would require lots of time and effort and may not be worth it.